# Null String when inserting characters (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am currently working on a text editing program in C, which uses Linked Lists for rows of text. I have so far written functions for resizing the list etc., but I have now attempted to write the `insert_char(Row* row, int idx, char c)` however whenever I try resizing it, the resulting `char*` array is `NULL`. I am confident it's not a memory leak, as I have checked and I am `free()`ing all of my `malloc()`'d memory, so I really don't know where the problem is.

I have also tried some `printf("%c", c)` debugging to view the character, however the character itself is also `NULL`. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the `struct` for a `Row`:

```
typedef struct {
    char* data; // pointer to Malloc()'d char array.
    int datalen;
} Row;
```

Here are the functions for resizing the row and allocating the `Row` pointer.

```
Row* alloc_row(char* data)
{
    Row* row = (Row*) malloc(sizeof(Row));
    char* data2 = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(data))+1);
    strcpy(data2, data);
    row->data = data2;
    row->datalen = strlen(data);
    return row;
}

// Row resize

Row* resize_row(Row* oldrow, char* data)
{
    Row* new_row = (Row*) malloc(sizeof(Row));
    new_row->data = data;
    new_row->datalen = strlen(data);

    // free() the old row
    free(oldrow->data);
    free(oldrow);

    return new_row;
}
```

And here is the function I am having trouble with - it should take a `Row*`, create a buffer, `strcpy()` the `Row->data` up to `idx`, insert the `char c` and then copy the rest of the string afterwards, such that if I called `alloc_row(Row* {.data = "Hello" .strlen=5}, 2, 'A')` I would receive `HeAllo` (counting from zero). However, the string is `NULL`:

```
Row* insert_char(Row* row, int idx, char c)
{
    char* new_row = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(row->data) + 2)); // 1 char for null, char for the appended data
    if (idx < strlen(row->data)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(row->data)+1; i++) {
            if (i < idx) new_row[i] = row->data[i];
            if (i == idx) new_row[idx] = c;
            if (i > idx) new_row[i] = row->data[i-1];
        }
    } else {
        row->data[strlen(row->data)] = '\0';
        strncpy(new_row, row->data, strlen(row->data));
        new_row[strlen(row->data)-1] = c;
    }
    Row* nr = resize_row(row, new_row);
    return nr;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my approach, and is there a cleaner and faster way of doing this?

Comment: `row->data[strlen(row->data)] = '\0';` makes no sense as strlen uses the nul termination char to compute the length of the string

Comment: `new_row->data = data;` then `free(oldrow->data);` that's not okay: you're copying the input pointer and freeing the old memory block. You should duplicate the input string instead

Comment: All those duplicated strlen calls - so wasteful !

Comment: I know it was a bit pendantic, but at the point of writing that I started wondering if a bug like a missing null terminator was causing `strlen` to go off into memory.

Comment: plus no need to store the length of the string. Or stop calling strlen. Simplify your code, it's redundant. Also you're not showing how you're calling those functions.

Comment: That’s the reason the code is so untidy, as I wanted no room for error, and then I planned on going through to optimize later. I do appreciate it is an eyesore

Comment: `resize_row` doesn't seem like a good name. It doesn't resize anything.

Comment: …Yes it does - it resizes the data within the `Row` and attaches a new `char*` and also recomputes `strlen` which is the length (aka size) of the new data.

Comment: It allocates a memory for a new `Row` and assigns some pointers. It doesn't resize anything. You'd be better off using `alloc_row` and providing a new function to free a row.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**Not a string**

`new_row[]` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  Later code relies on that.
Result: *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
char* new_row = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(row->data) + 2));
if (idx < strlen(row->data)) {
  ...
} else {
    row->data[strlen(row->data)] = '\0';
    strncpy(new_row, row->data, strlen(row->data));
    // At this point `new_row[]` lacks a '\0'
    new_row[strlen(row->data)-1] = c;
}
```

It is unclear exactly what OP's wants in the else block, but I think it may be:

```
} else {
    size_t len = strlen(row->data);
    strcpy(new_row, row->data);
    new_row[len++] = c;
    new_row[len] = '\0';
}
```

**Minor: conceptually wrong size**

The below works OK because `(sizeof(char)` is 1.

```
char* data2 = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(data))+1);
```

But should be:

```
char* data2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(data) + 1));
```

Even *better*, drop the unneeded cast and size to the referenced object, not the type.

```
char* data2 = malloc(sizeof *data2 * (strlen(data) + 1u));
// or
char* data2 = malloc(sizeof data2[0] * (strlen(data) + 1u));
```

---

**Untested alternate code**

```
typedef struct {
  char *data; // pointer to Malloc()'d char array.
  //int datalen;
  size_t datalen;
} Row;

// Row* insert_char(Row *row, int idx, char c) {
Row* insert_char(Row *row, size_t idx, char c) {
  assert(c != 0);  // Unclear what OP wants in this case

  //char *new_row = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(row->data) + 2));
  // Why use strlen(row->data) when the length is in row->datalen ?
  // Since row->data was getting free'd later in OP's code,
  // let us just re-allocate instead and re-use the old row node.
  char *new_row = realloc(row->data, row->datalen + 2);
  assert(new_row); // TBD code to handle out-of-memory

  // When idx large, simply append
  if (idx > row->datalen) {
    idx = row->datalen;
  }

  // Shift the right side over 1
  memmove(new_row + idx + 1, new_row + idx, row->datalen - idx + 1);  // Moves \0 too
  new_row[idx] = c;

  row->data = new_row;
  row->datalen++;
  return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it works (I modified certain things to print it directly and corrected some of your suggestions on how to call the function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char* data; // pointer to Malloc()'d char array.
    int datalen;
} Row;

char* insert_char(Row* row, int idx, char c)
{
    char* new_row = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(row->data) + 2)); // 1 char for null, char for the appended data
    if (idx < strlen(row->data)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(row->data)+1; i++) {
            if (i < idx) new_row[i] = row->data[i];
            if (i == idx) new_row[idx] = c;
            if (i > idx) new_row[i] = row->data[i-1];
        }
    } else {
        row->data[strlen(row->data)] = '\0';
        strncpy(new_row, row->data, strlen(row->data));
        new_row[strlen(row->data)-1] = c;
    }
    return new_row;
}


int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", insert_char(&(Row) {.data = "Hello", .datalen=5}, 2, 'A'));

    return 0;
}
```

**However**, I think that your problem is in the `for` where you need **+2** instead of **+1** in the ending condition (since you are copying the entire array and `malloc` doesn't necessarly set the last `char` as `'\0'` [although `calloc` could do that]).

Comment: Minor: `int idx`, `int i`, better as `size_t` to match the type returned by `strlen()`.

Comment: Well, actually I would change more things, but I tried to keep everything as similar as the code from the question, adding just my suggestion at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using some of your great ideas, I have come up with the following sample which uses `calloc()` to initialise a section of memory to 0. I believe my issue was in fact a missing `NULL` byte, and I have also cleaned things significantly. Here is my improved snippet:

```
Row* insert_char(Row* row, int idx, char* str)
{
    char* new_row = calloc(row->datalen + strlen(str) + 1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(new_row, row->data, idx);
    strcat(new_row, str);
    strcat(new_row, row->data + idx);

    return resize_row(row, new_row);
}
```

NOTE: I have modified the input from a `char` to a `char*` because I plan to be inserting strings in the future, and not just single characters.

The same `resize_row()` method is used as in the original:

```
Row* resize_row(Row* oldrow, char* data)
{
    Row* new_row = (Row*) malloc(sizeof(Row));
    new_row->data = data;
    new_row->datalen = strlen(data);

    // free() the old row
    free(oldrow->data);
    free(oldrow);

    return new_row;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(new_row, str); strcat(new_row, row->data + idx);` uses the inefficient [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).  Instead, `strcpy(new_row + idx, str); strcat(new_row + idx, row->data + idx);`

Comment: Why are you allocating a `Row` and then freeing a `Row`?  Better to use the `Row` over again and skip the unneeded `malloc(sizeof(Row)); ... free(oldrow);`.